# Query common column shared by records that only have certain IDs and no others?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in my DB:

```
people_to_groups

id   | personID | groupID
-------------------------
1    | 5        | 2
-------------------------
2    | 6        | 2
-------------------------
3    | 7        | 3
-------------------------
4    | 5        | 3
-------------------------
5    | 5        | 4
-------------------------
6    | 5        | 7
-------------------------
7    | 6        | 7
```

I'm trying to figure out a query that returns each `groupID` containing BOTH `personID` 5 and 6 ONLY and no other `personID`.

So if the query ran on the above table, it would return the following result set:

```
groupID
-------
2
-------
7
```

Because groups 2 and 7 are the only groups that have both persons 5 and 6 and no other people.

(PS if anyone can think of a better title please do suggest an edit)

Comment: The data set isn't very representative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer by Vashi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030254/3215948) is cool, but you can only use it when your selection group is continuous (e.g. 5 & 6 or 5 & 6 & 7, not 5 & 8). To cover all cases, you can use a straightforward translation of the requirements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT groupID
FROM people_to_groups
WHERE personID  = 5
  AND groupID IN (SELECT groupID
                  FROM people_to_groups
                  WHERE personID = 6)
  AND groupID NOT IN (SELECT groupID
                      FROM people_to_groups
                      WHERE personID NOT IN (6 , 5));
```

This is easy to understand, select all groups for 5, add groups for 6, and finally remove all groups for other numbers.

Alternatively, if you like the grouping idea in Vashi's answer, you can modify it to cover all cases:

```
SELECT groupID
FROM people_to_groups
WHERE personID IN (6 , 5)
  AND groupID NOT IN (SELECT groupID
                      FROM people_to_groups
                      WHERE personID NOT IN (6 , 5))
GROUP BY groupID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT personID) = 2;
```

So the same idea here, we're looking for groups that only have 2 distinct numbers and we define these two numbers to be 5 & 6. The only difference here is that instead of defining 5 & 6 as a range (i.e. min = 5 and max = 6), we actually restrict the search to 5 & 6 and then remove all other numbers.

Which one of the two solution to use depends on the situation. The first one is straightforward and easier to understand, but if you have several numbers in the selection group (e.g. 5 & 6 & 8 & 10), then you'll end up with many subqueries. In that case the second solution will be more manageable because it will stay the same and you just add all numbers you want in the `IN()` and `NOT IN()` parts.

Comment: For the second solution you'd also have to change the last line's ... = 2; to the number of personIDs in the selection group right?

Answer (score 3):

To make sure that the groupid has both 5 and 6, you can use these three rules:
1 - Max is 6
2 - Min is 5
3 - Count of Distinct personid is 2

```
SELECT groupID
FROM people_to_groups
GROUP BY groupID
HAVING MAX(personID) = 6 
   AND MIN(personID) = 5
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT personID) = 2;
```

Comment: For completeness `= greatest(6,5)` seems more obviously scalable